# "theme: ThemeData..." apparently ignored starting with Flutter 2.5.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working through the `startup_namer` tutorial example from flutter.dev. Here's the definition of `MyApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Startup Name Generator',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // Add the 3 lines from here...
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
        ), // ... to here.
        home: RandomWords());
  }
}
```

It used to be that when I ran the app, the title bar would be white.  But now, it retains the default (blue) theme.  Looks like either `ThemeData` or at least `primaryColor` are being ignored.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe check the [whats new guide](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-5-6f080c3f3dc)

Comment: Started leanring flutter today and i am facing this same problem

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties) and this quote from the Flutter-Team:

> The ThemeData accentColor, accentColorBrightness, accentIconTheme and
> accentTextTheme properties have been deprecated.
>
> The Material Design spec no longer specifies or uses an “accent” color
> for the Material components. The default values for component colors
> are derived from the overall theme’s color scheme. The ColorScheme’s
> secondary color is now typically used instead of accentColor and the
> onSecondary color is used when a contrasting color is needed.

Also checkout the migration guide.

**Regarding your appBar problem do this within the ThemeData():**

```
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a regression: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89839.
Nowhere on the Flutter site does it say that `primaryColor` has been deprecated.